# Xvfb not found on your system (Headless::Exception) in mac

Tags: ruby, headless, xvfb

/Users/ct/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/headless-1.0.2/lib/headless/cli_util.rb:9:in `ensure_application_exists!': Xvfb not found on your system (Headless::Exception)
    from /Users/ct/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/headless-1.0.2/lib/headless.rb:68:in`initialize'
    from c_1319.rb:9:in `new'
    from c_1319.rb:9:in`'

Comment: I bet you should install X.Org X Window System on your computer first. Could start from there: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Answer (score 9):

Installing [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) fixed the problem with me.

Comment: You may also need to add `/usr/X11/bin` to your PATH. Run `which xvfb` to see where (if at all) it's installed.

Comment: I had an additional problem on macOS with `Display socket is taken but lock file is missing - check the Headless troubleshooting guide (Headless::Exception)`. I used [this GH comment](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/issues/80#issuecomment-278182878) to fix.